# Apply if condition on a Dataframe

Tags: python

I want to loop over my dataframe and select every single month.

Then i want to see if an indicator equals high or low and if so, select only certain variables.

My code looks like this:

```
#Sorting date range and taking top 10 values and append these to account
start_date = date(2003, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 12, 1)
highest = []
lowest = []


while start_date <= end_date:
   
    end_of_month = start_date + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1) #Calculate end of month
    port = preds_vix.loc[start_date:end_of_month] #Select date range
    
    #Apply if condition to filter for high and low Signals

    if preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'High':
        port = port[vix_high] #Select factors that perform well/badly during high vix
        
        for i in list(vix_high_short):
            port_l = port.sort_values(i)
            low = port_l.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
        
        for i in list(vix_high_long):
            port_h = port.sort_values(i)
            high = port_h.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
    
    
    
    elif preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'Low':
        port = port[vix_low] #Select factors that perform well/badly during high vix
        
        for i in list(vix_low_short):
            port_l = port.sort_values(i)
            low = port_l.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
        
        for i in list(vix_low_long):
            port_h = port.sort_values(i)
            high = port_h.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
      
    
    
    else:
        port = port.sort_values(by = 'bh1m_prediction') #sort data conditional on target value
        top = port.nlargest(5,['preds']) #take 10 highest values
        low = port.nsmallest(5, ['preds']) #take 10 lowest values
    
    
    
    ret_h = np.mean(top['bh1m_prediction']) #calculate mean return of each month of long stocks
    ret_l = np.mean(low['bh1m_prediction']) #calculate mean return of each month of short stocks
    
    
    highest.append(ret_h) #append all values to a list
    lowest.append(ret_l)
    
    start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+1) #move one month forward and repeat the process
```

However, i always get an error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-91-4bb929bb98fb> in <module>
     12 
     13 
---> 14     if preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'High':
     15         port = port[vix_high] #Select factors that perform well/badly during high vix
     16 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __nonzero__(self)
   1477     def __nonzero__(self):
   1478         raise ValueError(
-> 1479             f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "
   1480             "Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."
   1481         )

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Is it possible to apply a if condition on a dataframe to select values conditional on my Signal_1?

Comment: Which line causes the error?  Please provide a stacktrace. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the code above. You can see the stacktrace now.

Comment: Try `preds_vix[preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'High']`. This will return the rows (new dataframe) that match the condition.

Comment: No, i've tried this before. It didn't work. I think i need to use np.where() or something, but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

So if you see from the error, the crux of the issue is that you're trying to validate the entire column as be true/false. Which isn't possible. What we want to do is to go individually to each row and check if they're either High or Low. What I've done is created another column to keep track if Signal_1 was High or Low, and then go row by row.

```
#Sorting date range and taking top 10 values and append these to account
start_date = date(2003, 1, 1)
end_date = date(2019, 12, 1)
highest = []
lowest = []
preds_vix['is_signal_high'] = preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'High'
preds_vix['is_signal_low'] = preds_vix['Signal_1'] == 'Low'


for counter in range(0, len(preds_vix['Signal_1'])):
    while start_date <= end_date:
       
        end_of_month = start_date + relativedelta(months=1, days=-1) #Calculate end of month
        port = preds_vix.loc[start_date:end_of_month] #Select date range
        
        #Apply if condition to filter for high and low Signals
    
        if preds_vix['is_signal_high'][counter]:
            port = port[vix_high] #Select factors that perform well/badly during high vix
            
            for i in list(vix_high_short):
                port_l = port.sort_values(i)
                low = port_l.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
            
            for i in list(vix_high_long):
                port_h = port.sort_values(i)
                high = port_h.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
        
        
        
        elif preds_vix['is_signal_low'][counter]:
            port = port[vix_low] #Select factors that perform well/badly during high vix
            
            for i in list(vix_low_short):
                port_l = port.sort_values(i)
                low = port_l.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
            
            for i in list(vix_low_long):
                port_h = port.sort_values(i)
                high = port_h.nlargest(1,['bh1m_prediction'])
          
        
        
        else:
            port = port.sort_values(by = 'bh1m_prediction') #sort data conditional on target value
            top = port.nlargest(5,['preds']) #take 10 highest values
            low = port.nsmallest(5, ['preds']) #take 10 lowest values
        
        
        
        ret_h = np.mean(top['bh1m_prediction']) #calculate mean return of each month of long stocks
        ret_l = np.mean(low['bh1m_prediction']) #calculate mean return of each month of short stocks
        
        
        highest.append(ret_h) #append all values to a list
        lowest.append(ret_l)
        
        start_date = start_date + relativedelta(months=+1) #move one month forward and repeat the process
```